# How do I hide the next/today/previous navigation in jQuery DatePicker and turn off animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

How do I hide the **prev/today/next** navigation in jQuery DatePicker?

I'm happy with just the Month and Year drop down boxes.

Also how do I disable the animations?

[@tvanfosson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316147/how-do-i-hide-the-nexttodayprevious-navigation-in-jquery-datepicker-and-turn-of#316153) - I already tried `hideIfNoPrevNext` but that only works if you don't have a date range that spans two months.

The duration option did the trick at turning off the animations though.

Cheers.

Answer (score 10):

You can find the options for the DatePicker control at http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/datepicker#options.  Specifically, I think you want to set hideIfNoPrevNext to true and set duration to ''.

```
  $('#cal').datepicker( { hideIfNoPrevNext: true, duration: '' } );
```

Answer (score 6):

Just hide buttons

```
$("div.ui-datepicker-header a.ui-datepicker-prev,div.ui-datepicker-header a.ui-datepicker-next").hide();
```

Answer (score 4):

Just modify the style to display none.

```
div.ui-datepicker-header 
a.ui-datepicker-prev,div.ui-datepicker-header 
a.ui-datepicker-next
{
    display: none;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I too experienced this problem with DatePicker's default functionality. 
I was missing the link to jquery.ui.base.css. After including a ref to this file on my page, it worked like a charm. I did not have to tweak any css or did not have to set any property. Fyi.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I found another way to do this. I used this one.

```
.focus(function () {
    $(".ui-datepicker-next").hide();
    $(".ui-datepicker-prev").hide();
});
```

You can do it like this..

```
$('#TextDateId').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "MM dd yyyy",
        changeMonth: true,
    }).focus(function () {
        $(".ui-datepicker-next").hide();
        $(".ui-datepicker-prev").hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to show/hide the prev/next navigation

```
.datepicker().focus(function () {
    $(".ui-datepicker-next").hide();
    $(".ui-datepicker-prev").hide();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

use this code, it will definitely work for stop navigation of next or prev button..

```
$("#cal").datepicker({
stepMonths: 0
)};
```

Comment: if you are using date-picker two or more times in your form then you can use this code for specially any one calendar .

Comment: Have you noticed that this question is more than 8 years old?!? and also the OP has stated that he had been able to solve the problem himself

Comment: yup i noticed @EhsanT bt i think that solutions is not working according to problem, so i cleared answer...